# React-Native- Fastlane build iOS Archive failed on CircleCI

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, circleci, fastlane

I'm trying to resolve this issue, already searched the similar issues on Stackoverflow or Github, but none of them are worked.
When the xcode version is set as "13.0.0", it worked properly. But recently it's failed, so I changed xcode version as "13.4.1", then there is another issue.

```
 Running script 'Bundle React Native code and images'
    the transform cache was reset.
▸ Generating 'QA2\ -\ *********.app.dSYM'
▸ Running script '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'
▸ Running script '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration'
▸ Running script '[CP-User] [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration'
▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
▸ Touching QA2\ -\ *********.app (in target '*********Staging' from project '*********Staging')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Run custom shell script 'Run Script'
(1 failure)
[22:27:52]: Exit status: 65
[22:27:52]: 
[22:27:52]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[22:27:52]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[22:27:52]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[22:27:52]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-13.4.1.app'
[22:27:52]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[22:27:52]: 
[22:27:52]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[22:27:52]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[22:27:52]: 
[22:27:52]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[22:27:52]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[22:27:52]: 
[22:27:52]: - Manually update the path using
[22:27:52]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Also, I found on the CircleCI, there are 2 Xcode versions[image]

How to fix this issue? it's the issue on CircleCI or Fastlane?

The another question I have is how to set only one Xcode-13.4.1 as default one.